# How to approximate $\sqrt[n]{x+y}$ using Newton's method

Tags: approximation, newton-raphson

Can anyone show me how you would work out, basically, $nth$ roots? Say you want to approximate the value of $\sqrt[n]{x+y}$, how would you use Newton's method using:
$$x_{k+1}=x_k+\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$
One approximation from [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#nth_root_algorithm) gives an approximation of the $nth$ root:
$$\sqrt[n]{x^n+y}=x+\frac{y}{nx^{n-1}}$$
However, the approximation is not exactly very exact especially with small numbers. Hope anyone can usher me in.

Comment: “with small numbers”? You mean when $x$ is small and $y$ is large? Or what?

Comment: The source that you cite answers your question precisely but does warn you that the result quoted by you is only the first in a sequence of approximations. It will work fine if you take a few iterations. If you want a method that always gives an accurate answer without much work you will not find anything, but you should use your intelligence to make the first guess as good as you can.

Comment: You have a function of two variables but then give Newton's method for one variable.